GDELT search ignoring language and country parameters
I'm writing a .Net MAUI app which I want to return news on a number of configurable topics on an on-demand basis.  I'm playing around with GDELT right now but I'm finding, despite following the API guide, my queries are ignoring parameters like sourcecountry and sourcelang.  So an example query is below:

https://api.gdeltproject.org/api/v2/doc/doc?query=("americas cup" OR "emirates team new zealand")&mode=ArtList&sourcelang=english&sourcecountry=nzl&timespan=1day&maxrecords=10&format=JSON

When I get the results back there are stories in French, Chinese and other non-English languages and almost none of the stories are from New Zealand.  Even if I try with other, more common searches (e.g "US election 2024") and parameters such as sourcecountry=usa I still get stories from everywhere and in various languages - here the top two stories are from India!
"articles": [
    {
        "url": "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/us/barack-obama-to-start-us-election-2024-campaign-for-kamala-harris-against-donald-trump-check-date/articleshow/113949564.cms",
        "url_mobile": "https://m.economictimes.com/news/international/us/barack-obama-to-start-us-election-2024-campaign-for-kamala-harris-against-donald-trump-check-date/amp_articleshow/113949564.cms",
        "title": "Barack Obama Kamala Harris : Barack Obama to start US election 2024 campaign for Kamala Harris against Donald Trump . Check date",
        "seendate": "20241004T203000Z",
        "socialimage": "https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-113949576,width-1200,height-630,imgsize-57350,overlay-economictimes/photo.jpg",
        "domain": "economictimes.indiatimes.com",
        "language": "English",
        "sourcecountry": "India"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/us/nfl-vs-mma-james-harrison-to-fight-chad-ochocinco-johnson/articleshow/113949600.cms",
        "url_mobile": "https://m.economictimes.com/news/international/us/nfl-vs-mma-james-harrison-to-fight-chad-ochocinco-johnson/amp_articleshow/113949600.cms",
        "title": "James Harrison : NFL vs MMA : James Harrison to fight Chad Ochocinco Johnson",
        "seendate": "20241004T203000Z",
        "socialimage": "https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-113949605,width-1200,height-630,imgsize-52240,overlay-economictimes/photo.jpg",
        "domain": "economictimes.indiatimes.com",
        "language": "English",
        "sourcecountry": "India"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://apnews.com/article/california-digest-c06760ec1ea2304bd37d8252680c1d82",
        "url_mobile": "",
        "title": "AP News Digest - California",
        "seendate": "20241004T214500Z",
        "socialimage": "",
        "domain": "apnews.com",
        "language": "English",
        "sourcecountry": "United States" 
     ...etc...

I can't find any GDELT forum or support page to ask this so hoping someone here might be able to help me identify what the issue is here.

according to this post the correct syntax is sourcecountry:US sourcelang:English
